# Passing type parameter to interface of base class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

StateBase implements iState

WolfState ineherits from StateBase

WolfController inherits from ControllerBase

I want to be able to do a

- WolfState that uses WolfController inheriting from State
- SheepState
  that uses SheepController and inherits from State

WolfController and SheepController would both inherit from StateController.

How should i declare WolfState?

The way i try to do it doesnt work.

```
   public interface IState <T> where T : StateController 
{
}

public abstract class State<T> where T : StateController,  IState<T> 
{
}

// THIS IS HOW I WOULD LIKE TO DO IT BUT ITS NOT ACCEPTED
public class WolfState : State<WolfController>
{
}

public class SheepState : State<SheepController>
{
}
```

Comment: `public class WolfState : State<WolfController>`?

Comment: @Lee Sorry! Thats what i meant to write. I have updated my question. So that is what does not work.

Comment: Does `WolfController` extend `StateController`? What's the error you receive?

Comment: Yes thats correct. WolfController and SheepController both extend StateController. 

"No implicit reference conversion from 'WolfController' to 'IState<WolfController>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you intend `State<T>` to implement `IState<T>`. You currently have a constraint on the type of `T`. Change the definition of `State<T>` to:

```
public abstract class State<T> : IState<T> where T : StateController
{
}
```

Comment: YES! Thank you. good to know i was thinking correctly anyway. Just didnt know how to implement it. Thanks a million!